# Average number of particles in a Fermi gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, fermions, chemical-potential

I want look (and plot) how the average number of fermions depends on temperature and the chemical potential.

According to Eq.(13.12) in [https://itp.uni-frankfurt.de/~gros/Vorlesungen/TD/13_Ideal_Fermi_gas.pdf](https://itp.uni-frankfurt.de/%7Egros/Vorlesungen/TD/13_Ideal_Fermi_gas.pdf), the fermion density $n$ is given by $$n = \frac{2s+1}{\lambda^3}f_{\frac{3}{2}}(z),$$

where $2s+1$ is the spin degeneracy, $\lambda^3 = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi \beta \hbar^2}{m}}$ is the de Broglie wavelength and $$f_{\frac{3}{2}}(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{z^n}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}},$$ with $z = e^{\beta\mu}$ being the fugacity.

Now, in the classical limit, i.e. high temperatures ($T\to \infty$), we have the condition $z \ll 1$.

However, I don't understand how exactly we get this condition. We can rewrite $z$ as $z = e^{\frac{\mu}{k_B T}}$. For $T \to \infty$, we have $\frac{\mu}{k_B T} \to 0$ for some fixed $\mu$ and therefore $z \to 1$.

1. How do we get that $z \ll 1$?
2. Since $\mu \in \mathbb R$, i.e. it can be negative and positive (whereas bosons have the restriction $\mu < 0$), how does this affect the condition $z \ll 1$ ?

Comment: The chemical potential is also a function of temperature and you need to know how it behaves as $T\to\infty$ to determine what that limit's behaviour will actually be.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent thanks! is there a possibility to determine the behavior of $\mu$ without going to the degenerate case first? Cause in the script, when going to the degenerate case for $T > 0$, there is an expression (Eq. 13.27)  for $\mu$ and how it depends on $T$

Comment: No, I think you are going about it the wrong way. The text explicitly says that the classical limit corresponds to $0<\frac{\left<N\right>}V\lambda^3\ll1$, and then comparing with Equation (13.9), we see that this means that $f_{\frac32}(z)\to0^+$; now, this is an infinite series, but it is clear that it will only be nearly zero if $z\to0^+$ too, and that is why we can deduce that $\beta\mu\to-\infty$

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I think I understand now what You mean. But doesn't the fact that $\beta \mu \to -\infty$ has to be fullfiled means that $\mu < 0$ ? And since for fermions $\mu > 0$ can also be the case, how can then $\beta \mu \to -\infty$  ?

Comment: It is simple to see that as $T$ increases from zero to infinity, the chemical potential $\mu$ starts from positive and move towards negative infinity. There might be regions in which it wavers, but the classical limit involves it going towards -ve infinity faster than $T$ moves towards +ve infinity.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent sorry, but where exactly can we see that $\mu$ starts from positive and moves towards $-\infty$ ?

Comment: No, we cannot see that, but it is the standard behaviour once you see enough fermion systems behaving this way. The idea is that you need $\mu\ll0$ in order for the Fermi-Dirac distribution to look like Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent okay... so to plot the average number of fermions, i can take $\frac{\mu}{T}$ and take the limit $\frac{\mu}{T} \to -\infty$ and use it for plotting the dependecy of the average number of particles on $\frac{\mu}{T}$ ? Since I don't know the actual dependency of $\mu$ on $T$, only that $\mu \to -\infty$ faster than $T \to \infty$.

Comment: I think so. It is not an thing to do theoretically, but it is very easy to do computer simulations and numerical study thereof.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent thank You again very mcuh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine how to get the high temperature limit at fixed number of particles, you just need to use the formula for the expected number of particles:
$$
N = \sum_n\frac{1}{e^{\beta E_n}/z+1}
$$
The RHS is an increasing function for $T$ and an increasing function for $z$. Therefore, at fixed $N$, $z$ is a decreasing function of $T$. In the high temperature limit, fugacity decreases and converges to a finite limit $z\to z_\infty$. The question is therefore why is $z_\infty=0$.

The short answer is that this is not always the case. Take for example a two orbital system, $n\in\{1,2\}$, with a single fermion, $N=1$, $z_\infty$ is finite.

In most applications, the number of orbitals is large compared to the number of fermions. Take for example the gas in a box (as in your case), harmonic oscillator, etc. where the number of orbitals is rigorously infinite. Note that this still holds even in the thermodynamic limit where you let number of fermions $N\to\infty$. In this case, for finite $z_\infty$, the RHS would go to infinity, so this imposes $z_\infty=0$.

The fact that $\mu$can be both positive or negative does not affect the high temperature limit. Indeed, since $z\to0$, $\mu\to-\infty$. In fact, you get the dilute limit in which all the statistics (Maxwell-Boltzmann, Fermi-Dirac, Bose-Einstein) agree.

Hope this helps.